# How do I plot close compared to EMA on 3 timeframes in pine-script?

Tags: pine-script

How do I get the plotting to work so that if price is above EMA on these 3 TF's, it will show green and if its below on any of the TF's, it will show red?  Right now its's showing both and it should only show one color vs the other.

I tried this:

plot((ema1? 1:0) + (ema2? 1:0) + (ema3? 1:0), style=plot.style_columns, color=color.lime)

plot((ema1? 0:-1) + (ema2? 0:-1) + (ema3? 0:-1), style=plot.style_columns, color=color.red)

```
// All credits go to CMoody for the original Idea...
study(title="3-EMA MTF", shorttitle="3_EMA_MTF", precision=0, overlay=false)
//@version=4

//candle source
src = input(close, title="Source")
col = input(title="Color EMA", type=input.bool, defval=true)

//first EMA inputs
//firstEMATimeframe = input(title="Select 1st EMA Timeframe", type=resolution, defval="1D")
len  = input(200, minval=1, title="1st EMA Length")

//second EMA inputs
isDisplaySecondEMA = input(false, title="Show 2nd EMA?")
//secondEMATimeframe = input(title="Select 2nd EMA Timeframe? Check Box Above", type=resolution, defval="12H")
len2 = input(200, minval=1, title="2nd EMA Length")

//third EMA inputs
isDisplayThirdEMA = input(false, title="Show 3rd EMA?")
//thirdEMATimeframe = input(title="Select 3rd EMA Timeframe? Check Box Above", type=resolution, defval="4H")
len3 = input(200, minval=1, title="3rd EMA Length")

//calculate 1st EMA values
out = ema(src, len)
resCustom = input(title="EMA Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="720")
value1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, resCustom, out, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

//calculate 2nd EMA values
out2 = ema(src, len2)
resCustom2 = input(title="EMA Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="240")
value2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, resCustom2, out2, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

//calculate 3rd EMA values
out3 = ema(src, len3)
resCustom3 = input(title="EMA Timeframe", type=input.resolution, defval="60")
value3 = security(syminfo.tickerid, resCustom3, out3, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
//plot EMA column
//plot(close >= value1, value2, value3, title="Buy", style=columns, color=lime)
//plot(close < value1, value2, value3, title="Sell", style=columns, color=red)

ema1 = close >= value1
ema2 = close >= value2
ema3 = close >= value3

plot((ema1? 1:0) + (ema2? 1:0) + (ema3? 1:0), style=plot.style_columns, color=color.lime)
plot((ema1? 0:-1) + (ema2? 0:-1) + (ema3? 0:-1), style=plot.style_columns, color=color.red)
```

This is what it will look like if code is correct
[image]

it currently looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### **It looks like you added more parameters to the plot function than it allows.**

```
plot(close >= value1, value2, value3, title="Buy", style=columns, color=lime)
```

You cannot just *make up* new parameters for a built-in function.
The proper format for the plot function is:

```
plot(series, title, color, linewidth, style, trackprice, transp, histbase, offset, join, editable, show_last, display) → plot
```

*So essentially you are telling the script to plot*

```
plot(series= close >= value1, title=value2, color= value3, title="Buy", style= "columns", color=red)
```

**So you are calling the function with duplicate parameters: *2 colors and 2 titles***

---

**What you need to do instead is check the close for each expression separately** and one way to do that is to create variables for each expression like this:

```
ema1 = close >= value1
ema2 = close >= value2
ema3 = close >= value3
plot(ema1 and ema2 and ema3)
plot(not ema1 and not ema2 and not ema3)
```

Or the more messy method:

```
plot(close >= ema1 and close >= ema2 and close >= ema3)
```

But this would be redundant because you have two plots

Alternatively, another option would to call each security function with the expression instead of just the EMA value:

```
value1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, resCustom, close >= out, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

This would give value1 a boolean value (true or false) so now you could simply use

```
plot(value1 and value2 and value3)
plot(not value1 and not value2 and not value3)
```

---

**When you are using the 'and' operator, it checks to see if ALL expressions are true before plotting. If you wanted to to plot if only ONE of the three expressions is true then you would use the 'or' operator**

```
plot(value1 or value2 or value3)
```

---

That isn't even mentioning your incorrect variables: **'red', 'lime' and 'columns'**

In PineScript version 4 (which you are using), colors are defined like this

```
color.red
color.lime
// color= color.red
// color= color.lime
```

and styles like this:

```
plot.style_columns
// style= plot.style_columns
```

### ***In the future, you could have easily found this information by simply holding CTRL and clicking any function (such as plot) and it will show you all the parameters that it accepts***

Comment: thanks for your help and explanation.. I almost have it working correctly!